# Finding the permutation induced. (Group Actions)

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given : $r$ is the rotation of a square clockwise by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ radians and $s$ be the reflection in the line which passes through the vertices $1$ and $3$ of the square given as :

[image]

Let $G = D_8$ and $H = <s>$ , we are defining a group action as , $G$ acting on the left cosets of $H$ in $G$ as : $$g \wedge aH = gaH$$

Now we need to find the permutation $ \sigma_s$ induced by the group action .

Writing the left cosets as $$ \{ 1H , rH ,r^{2}H , r^{3}H\}$$

So , $s$ acts on them as follows :

(1) $ s \wedge 1H = sH = 1H$

(2) $ s \wedge rH = srH = r^{3}H$

I got stuck in the (2) part ..

As per my calculations with the figure used above I got $ r = (1432)$ and $s = (24)$ , so ,

$sr = (12)(34)$ and $r^{3} = (1234)$ , how are these equal ?

Am I doing something wrong ? Could anyone tell ?

Comment: Shouldn't $\sigma_r = (1\ 2\ 3\ 4)$?  Also, why do you think $\sigma_{sr} = \sigma_{r^3}$?  Certainly $sr$ and $r^3$ are equal modulo $H$, but here you should be treating them as elements of $G$, where they are certainly not equal.

Comment: Could you explain that - " $sr$ and $r^{3}$ are equal modulo $H$ " ? @SpamIAm

Comment: It just means that $srH = r^3H$ in $G/H$, which follows from $sr = r^3 s$.

Comment: Got it .. thanks !